# Fibonacci function with list comprehension returns None

Tags: python, function, list-comprehension

Returns [None,None,None,None,None]

```
def perimeter(num):
    lst = [1]
    return [lst.append(n+lst[lst.index(n)-1]) for n in lst if len(lst) <= num]

print(perimeter(5))
```

Comment: Here is an existing question about [creating the fibonacci series using a list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42370456/14627505).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does append() always return None in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641119/why-does-append-always-return-none-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lst.append(...)` doesn't return anything (more precisely, returns `None`).

Your function returns the list created with the [list comprehenshion](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) . This list contains 5 **results** of `lst.append(...)` - which are all `None`.

---

What you *technically can* do, is return `lst` from the function:

```py
def perimeter(num):
    lst = [1]
    [lst.append(n+lst[lst.index(n)-1]) for n in lst if len(lst) <= num]
    return lst
```

```py
print(perimeter(5))
[1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
```